# JWPlayer/Video: how can I setup a wildcard ID so I can have multiple videos on the same page

Tags: html, video, jwplayer

Here's the deal:
I have a wordpress blog where I use bits of video.
In order for the html5 player (JWPlayer) to work, in a page full of other videos, I have to give a unique ID to each video and have a unique setup with that ID. In practice, this means that for each post I have something like this:

```
            <video id="video1" poster="http://url.com/name.jpg">
              <source src="http://url.com/name.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="http://url.com/name.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              jwplayer("video1").setup({
                modes: [
                    { type: 'html5' },
                    { type: 'flash', src: '/player/player.swf' }
                ],
                'skin': '/player/skin/minima.zip',
              });
            </script>
```

This setup is already working, yet in the name of having a less cluttered post/content and to avoid having the same minima.zip skin loaded 10 times each page (the number of posts), is there a way that I can take this bit of setup script out of the post/content and create a wildcard for the jwplayer ID to match the video ID in the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really do need to set multiple IDs for each player set up / div. I am not sure if a wildcard ID will work.